# knitr and font style consistency in graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, graphics, r, knitr

I am starting to use **knitr** to print graphics from R in my document. So far what I have been doing (I don't know if this is the best approach, but it is working) is to load the my R workspace with

```
<<prepare-data, include=FALSE>>=
load("~/Desktop/r_work_directory/workspace.RData")
@
```

after the preamble, then calling an R script to produce the graphics with

```
<<child-foo, child='figure/foo.R', include=FALSE>>=
@
```

and finally adding the figure with

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\paperwidth]{figure/foo.pdf}}
  \caption{This is Foo} 
      \label{fig:Foo}
\end{figure}
```

The only thing I couldn't get with this method is to have the fonts in the graphics to match those in my document. I saw in the **knitr** manual that consistency is given (only?) through the **tikzDevice**. Unfortunately the **tikzDevice** package is not available with **R** 3.0.

Is there any other approach to get font style consistency?

Comment: tikzDevice was only archived on CRAN; it was not deleted, and you can still install from source, e.g. `install.packages('tikzDevice', repos='http://r-forge.r-project.org', type='source')`

Comment: It worked! I managed to install it from source. I had to first `install.packages('filehash')` and then `install.packages("~/Downloads/tikzDevice_0.6.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")`

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. That is exactly what you need to do. I really hope one day someone can bring tikzDevice back to CRAN (I have said this many times...). Anyway, please feel free to write an answer to your own question.

Comment: If anyone is trying to install `tikzDevice` on a Mac, by following the suggestions in these comments, you need the `llvm-gcc-4.2` compiler installed on your machine. Previously, you could get this on your machine by installing Xcode and the command line tools. However, Apple deprecated support for `llvm-gcc` in Xcode 5. The simplest solution that I found was just to download Xcode 4 from Apple's Developer website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to install **tikzDevice** on Mac running R 3.0 executing the following from R console:

```
install.packages('filehash')
install.packages("~/Downloads/tikzDevice_0.6.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

With the **tikzDevice** I could let `knitr` producing my plots with the same font family used in the rest of the document.

In the .Rnw document I added

```
<<prepare-data, include=FALSE>>=
load("~/Desktop/r_work_directory/workspace.RData")
@
```

to load my pre-saved R workspace, so to call R objects previously created directly from the `knitr` chucks embedded (as the following) in the `\figure` environment of my document.

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering

  <<my-plot, dev='tikz', fig.width=6, fig.height=3, out.width='.95\\textwidth', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
  plot(my_R_object)
  @

  \caption{This is my plot} 
  \label{fig:my-plot}
\end{figure}
```